# How can I migrate my network+printer configurations into new Windows?

Tags: windows, local-area-network, network-printer, live-cd

One of my office Windows machine has been crashed( blue screen). I am browsing 
 my file system (crashed pc's drive(c:)) from my Ubuntu Live CD. I am setting up new OS on my crashed pc. I am looking for a way to copy my existing printers+network configurations to my new Windows.

So, how can I access network+printers configuration files from my live Ubuntu disk?
Where are my network+printer configuration files located in my hdd(c:)?

Comment: There is no way that I know of to export and import the settings from a livecd. You can try to retrieve the settings [from the registry](https://askubuntu.com/questions/135200/is-there-a-way-to-edit-the-windows-registry-from-ubuntu). But since you have to configure it manually afterwards anyway I doubt it's worth the hassle.

Comment: You can try to copy your profile, but you wqill not be able to migrate your printers drivers.